# How to make TISSUE blend between solid and wire frame?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, add-on, weight-painting

[Blend file here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dFndvXWQO30Tvy0X_iXZ8aNRmHXqj2Q8?usp=sharing)Okay, so I'm messing with tissue and some other techniques to create an object that has two areas blended or have a gradient. The first area will be solid/flat, and the second area will have holes.

I tried masking using vertex group along side using weight mode to specify areas that I  want the holes to stay.

I tried weight mode before adding wire frame modifier in order to only apply on the areas I didn't do in weight mode.

Blend file attached alongside a reference of what I'm trying to achieve.

Thank you.[[image: REFERENCE PHOTOBLEND FILE IS HERE]

Comment: assign vertex group

Comment: I did. please take a look at the blend file and the reference photo to get my point.